# Rails 3.1 assets gives me asset not precompiled error whereas I can see the asset in the assets directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, assets

On my Rails 3.1 production installation I get the error:

`ActionView::Template::Error (jquery.case_by_email.js isn't precompiled)`

however, when I go to

`public/assets` folder I can see the file:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1225 Sep 16 12:56 jquery.case_by_email-acb70cf78973ab24fe65ae3d01a2d1ba.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  615 Sep 16 12:56 jquery.case_by_email-acb70cf78973ab24fe65ae3d01a2d1ba.js.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1225 Sep 16 12:56 jquery.case_by_email.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  615 Sep 16 12:56 jquery.case_by_email.js.gz`

I actually see 4 versions of this file. 2 with fingerprint one of which is gziped and 2 without fingerprint.

Note that I have the file specifically in the list of precompiles in my `application.rb` application configuration:

`# Extra .js for precompile. Files that are not included in manifests
config.assets.precompile += ['jquery.case_by_email.js']`

I am including this file in my view as follows:

`<% content_for :javascript_includes do %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.case_by_email" %>
<% end %>`

How can I track where the problem is? Other assets are normally found and served.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like something I had before. I forgot to precompile assets as production. A simple `export RAILS_ENV=production` followed by `rake assets:precompile` fixed it for me. Let me know if this is the case for you as well.

Comment: @anbiniyar This didn't work. I also see the file inside the `manifest.yml` file inside the public/assets directory.

Answer (score 0):

Add to ***config/environments/production.rb*** the following line:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: According to Rails Guides, "This mode uses more memory, performs more poorly than the default and is not recommended." And I suppose that it will require a Javascript runtime engine installed on production.

Comment: Touche. You have to precompile for best performance. This would just compile on the fly.